# How is my sequences and series proof?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ be a series of positive real numbers. Prove that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n}^r,$ where $r$ is a positive integer.

My solution:

If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then  $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0.$
Therefore, we can find a number $N$ large enough such that $a_n<1$ for all $n \geq N.$
We can write
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}^{r}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_{n}^{r}+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_{n}^{r}.$$
We know that there are a finite number of terms where $n < N,$ so the left series is finite and converges.
When $n \geq N,$ we know that $a_n^r \le a_n,$  as $r$ is a positive integer and $a_n<1.$
The comparison test then says that the right series converges.
Therefore, since both the left and right series converge, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n}^r$ also converges.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n^r<\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n$ is false (they both are $0$) but you can say that $a_n^r\leqslant a_n$ for $n$ large enough since $a_n<1$.

Comment: As per @Tuvasbien's comment, you should say $a_n^r \le a_n$ for large $n$, not $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^r \le \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$; the first inequality allows you to use the comparison test for series, but the second one does not.

Comment: How's my new solution?